# Can't get MS Office mass delpoyment working. Update Not Running?

Tags: windows, powershell, deployment, microsoft-office-2016

I am trying to mass deploy Office 2016 at work and I am testing it on one machine.

I am using the following scripts and instructions.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/blob/master/Office-ProPlus-Deployment/Deploy-OfficeClickToRun/1-ExampleDeployGeneric.ps1

I am able to run the script and I have all my configurations files in place and in the right directories. However after the UAC asks me if I want to run Office 2016 and I say yes, it errors out on my powershell screen as "Update Not Running"

Basically this is what happens after I run the script in powershell.

```
> Generate-ODTConfigurationCML -Languages AllInUseLanguages -TargetFilePath $targetFilePath | Set-ODTAdd - Version $NULL | Install-OfficeClickToRun

Installing Office Click-To-Run
Waiting for Update to Complete...
Update Not Running
```

It quits.

If anyone has any clue as to why, or if there are any Microsoft Experts out there that can help out, that would be great. I understand 2016 just came out, but it is debugging and trials like this that make it easier for others.

Comment: Also, someone please make an `microsoft-office-2016` tag, as it doesn't exist and my rep is too low to create it. Thank you

Comment: Have you opened the script and stepped through its actions?  If not, try that and it should identify the offending issue.  Or at least get you past "it don't work".

Comment: I have tried that, however it brings in some variables that are not to be found in the ps1 files at all. Which is why i'm looking for help from someone who knows powershell, has deployed this themself, or works at Microsoft.